# Efficient way to implement frequency table on interval data in Java

Tags: java, frequency

I am trying to create a frequency table to eventually create a histogram. The input data is of type `Double` and should all fall in the interval [-1;1]. I would like to divide this interval into bins with a width of e.g. .02 and count the occurrences of values in each interval, there is no need to store the data.

I tried using [Apache Commons Frequency](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/Frequency.html), but that only seems to work with discrete values.

Is there a library that achieves this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't been able to find a library that does what I wanted, here's the solution I came up with in case anyone finds this in the future:

I created a datatype representing an Interval similar to one I found in [Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/Interval.java.html).

The actual frequency table is implemented as a `TreeMap<Interval, Integer>`, since that is able to store the entries in the order of the keys (the `Interval` implementation needs a `Comparator` for this to work). Then all I needed to add was method to add observations, which increments the value of the interval in the `TreeMap`.

May not be the most efficient way to solve this, but it seems to work for my purposes.